# Serializable attribute .NET

Tags: .net, serialization, binary-serialization

I'm using Binary Serialization in .NET to clone objects.  Any of my own classes I must mark with the `<Serializable()>` attribute in order for the serializer to process the class.  However since this is a function that will be used on any object, I was wondering:

Is it possible to have the serializer serialize the object even if it isn't marked with the `<Serializable()>` attribute?  If not, is there a way to "auto-apply" the attribute to any class?

Edit.  My main concern is that I need to be able to clone POCO objects that already exist in the .NET Framework.  Are all those already serializable as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing how a class is implemented, it isn't safe to serialize it, and doing so could lead to subtly-broken objects.  That's why a class designer must intentionally add the `Serializable` attribute, letting the runtime know that this is a safe operation.  Automatically adding that attribute to any class is probably a bad idea.

If you really need to serialize a class that isn't `Serializable`, you can do it manually:

1. Figure out some way to convert your problem class to and from an alternate representation.
2. Use that other class for serialization, converting back and forth as necessary.

Failing that, you should look at other ways of preserving state besides serialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify attributes in runtime. Only in source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to iterate over the properties of any class/instance.
But you have to make a custom serializer.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET framework itself usually provides serialization support in all classes and structs where this does make sense, so it is likely that classes from the framework itself will work fine with your cloning. However, you may get in trouble if you use any 3rd-party libraries, which unfortunately quite often don't have proper serialization support.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using typeof(yourType).IsSerializable...